# Input inside a button style with twitter bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am trying add input boxes to a button type style.  My effort is below.  It works but the 'button' with the input box is much fatter (height) than the one without.  Is it possible to make the height the same?

```
<div class="btn btn-info">I'm nice and slim</div>
<div class="btn btn-info">help <input type="text" class="input-mini" placeholder="Type here"> I'm too fat!</div>
```

[image: fat button]

Comment: Have you tried setting the height of the button yourself?

Comment: Came here and implemented this. Then I realized this is a terrible idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
.btn > input {
    font-size: 11px;
    height: 16px;
    line-height: 16px;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    padding-bottom: 0;
    padding-top: 0;
}
```